# how to retrieve image from database and update it in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have an add image form and update image form. My code for uploading image works successfully. But now I want to retrieve and display image and also want to provide an update option with new one in update form. How to achieve both things in update form i.e if a user needs to update image, update it or if a user don't want to update, keep the same image.

```
Html code:

<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
<tr><td>Image:</td><td> <input type="file" name="image" value="<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" required></td></tr>

php code:

if(isset($_POST['edit']))
    { 
        $image=$_FILES['image']['name'];
        $target="images/".basename($image);
        include("dbConnect.php");

         $query="update image_table set image='$image' where id='$id'";
         $edit=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
         move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],$target);
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a proper question and improve yours according the guidelines. As a first step, please add the code you already tried and describe how it doesn't work for you. Also you should read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users and finally https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### To Display the image use

`<img src="yourdomain/image_storage_location/<?php echo $imagename; ?>">`

> Retrieve the image name from database as you saved on uploading.

### For Updating Image. Use as for Adding image.

> Use if Condition that user updated image with a new one or left it as it is

```
if($_FILES['file_input_type_name']){
   code for replace the old image
}else{
   $filenameToUploadToDatabase=$imagename;//Imagename you queried to view the image
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. It was helpful. :)

Comment: Can you help me out by providing the code w.r.t. my code above?

Comment: Be more descriptive about what you need. or inbox me on twitter.